# Are buffers shared between two GLSL programs?

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

In my app, I need to switch between two GLSL programs through glUseProgram(program). I am wondering if I write:

```
glUseProgram(program1)
buf1 = glGenBuffers(1)
glUseProgram(program2)
buf2 = glGenBuffers(1)
```

Can buf1 and buf2 be the same value? i.e. does each program have its own buffers or does they share buffers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating buffer objects is in no way affected by the current program. So calling `glUseProgram` has no effect on the creation of buffer objects. They are not associated with any programs that are in use.

Comment: Thus , I just need to activitate the program I want to use (glUseProgram)  before rendering ?